# TypeError: array(41.751585948319004) is not JSON serializable

Tags: arrays, json, python-2.7, serialization, scipy

My code is :

```
url = 'http://localhost:8000/blog/api/v1/entry/'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

f = np.squeeze(np.asarray(variables_t0[2]))
payload = {"pub_date": 'a', "Intensity": f}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

And I have this error:

`TypeError: array(41.751585948319004) is not JSON serializable`

Do you know how to convert an array to a json type ?

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I found how to change an array to a json by changing the type in a float :

```
f = np.float(variables_t0[2])
```